# Nginx proxy paths

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm trying to proxy another web server, on localhost:20000, from nginx. This works:

```
location/ {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:20000
}
```

However if I change it to:

```
location /myApp {
proxy_set_header..
```

I can only load the index.html file, all the other .css & .js 404. I can see in the browser's headers that the request for these files are going to  mysite.com/jquery.js instead of mysite.com/myApp/jquery.js, so I'm guessing they aren't being proxied at that point which is why they 404. The paths to these URLs are coded relatively (). How do I get this to work. I can't change the paths in the proxied index.html files. Thanks

Edit. The backend webserver is thttpd and it is ancient. Would this effect the set_head Host? Sorry I'm not very familiar with how that layer works.

Comment: I think this confirms my idea that thttpd isn't able to support the X-Forwarded-For tag thus the .js & .css header files going to the wrong place. http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,217330,217364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `location /myApp {}` must be above `location {}`. Second, what is probably more important, you can serve static files directly, by properly assigning `root` and adding a secion like this:

`location ~* \.(css|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|js|ico|swf|mp3)$ {
    break;
}`

If you want to modify the URI instead, this can be helpful, inside `location / {}` section:

`rewrite ^/(.*)$ /myApp/$1  break;`

Comment: That would work for what I showed but I dummied it down to get to the root cause. I'm really doing location ~ "^/[\d]{5}"{proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:$1}  which is why it's critical to re-write the proxy_set_head Host. Thanks this is better than nothing though.

Comment: Though even if I did find a way to get the ports static, I think this would route my host page's .css & .js to the wrong place.